# Predicate search not working (core data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data

When inserting in the "FilterProperty" entity, I use the following code in a category "FilterProperty+Manage.h"

```
+(FilterProperty *)insertFilterPropertyWithName:(NSString *)filterPropertyName forManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext forFriendlyName:(NSString *)friendlyName
                                forDefaultValue:(NSNumber *)defaultValue forMinValue:(NSNumber *)minValue forMaxValue:(NSNumber *)maxValue forType:(NSNumber *)type forBelongsToFilter:(Filter *)filter
{
    FilterProperty *fp = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@ AND belongsToFilter.name = %@", filterPropertyName, filter.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if (fetchedObjects != nil && fetchedObjects.count > 0)
    {
        fp = fetchedObjects.firstObject;
    }
    else if(fetchedObjects != nil && fetchedObjects.count == 0)
    {
        fp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        fp.name = filterPropertyName;
        fp.friendlyName = friendlyName;
        fp.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        fp.minValue = minValue;
        fp.maxValue = maxValue;
        fp.belongsToFilter = filter;
        fp.type = type;
    }

    return fp;
}
```

No while searching, I do the following:

```
+(NSArray *)getAllFilterPropertiesForFilter:(Filter *)filter forManagedObjectContext (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSArray *set = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToFilter.name = %@", filter.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    if(fetchedObjects != nil)
    {
        set = fetchedObjects;
    }

    return set;
}
```

The above function when called for any given filter is returning an array with zero objects. I am not able to get why. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try out this code for searching:-

```
+(NSArray *)getAllFilterPropertiesForFilter:(Filter *)filter forManagedObjectContext (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSArray *set = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToFilter.name == %@", filter.name];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    if(fetchedObjects != nil)
    {
        set = fetchedObjects;
    }

    return set;
}
```

Comment: So sorry for asking, but I don't see the change.

Comment: oh the == instead of the = ok

Comment: while inserting values you must add this code otherwise it will not save..NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{ 
}  and if it is not saving there is no possiblity of getting values..

Comment: turns out it was a mistake while inserting Filters... the return wasn't coming correctly so the filter i was passing was actually going nil in filter properties... fixed it... your == works. I'll try out = as well and tell you whether both work or not.

Comment: There is **no difference** between "=" and "==" in a predicate. Both work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your insertFilterPropertyWithName method you are not saving the new data. If I am correct, try this code after your if-else block:

```
NSError *error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    //could not save
}
```

Hope this could resolve your problem.

Comment: actually it was getting saved however there was silly mistake at my end... the method that inserted the filter was always returning nil. So all the filter properties were being related to nil. Sorry for wasting all of your time. :(

Answer (score 0):

In that below if condition you need to save in managedobjectcontext.

```
else if(fetchedObjects != nil && fetchedObjects.count == 0)
{
    fp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fp.name = filterPropertyName;
    fp.friendlyName = friendlyName;
    fp.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    fp.minValue = minValue;
    fp.maxValue = maxValue;
    fp.belongsToFilter = filter;
    fp.type = type;

    NSError *err = nil;
    [managedObjectContext save:&err];
    if (errorInWrite != nil) {
        //Problem while saving         
    }
}
```

Use like instead of "=" Hope it will be useful.

```
 +(NSArray *)getAllFilterPropertiesForFilter:(Filter *)filter forManagedObjectContext (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
NSArray *set = nil;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FilterProperty" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"belongsToFilter.name like %@", filter.name];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    return nil;
}

if(fetchedObjects != nil)
{
    set = fetchedObjects;
}

return set;
```

}

Comment: actually it was getting saved however there was silly mistake at my end... the method that inserted the filter was always returning nil. So all the filter properties were being related to nil. Sorry for wasting all of your time. :( BTW "=" and "==" both work in this case now.